# How to test bounds of a bidimensional array, to avoid indexOutOfRangeException (C#)

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array, indexoutofboundsexception

It's pretty simple to deal with an array with one dimension. But how can we avoid testing out of range locations within a bi dimensional array with different lengths on each row (jagged array)?

here is my code (if anyone wants to test):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    object[][] x = weirdReturn();

    int k = 0;
    while(x[0][k] != null) //THIS CODE PRODUCES THE EXCEPTION
    {
       for(int i = 0; i< x[k].Length; i++) 
        {
            Console.Write("{0} ", x[k][i]);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("");
        k++;
    }


}


static object[][] weirdReturn()
{           
    DateTime d = new DateTime();
    d = DateTime.Now;
    object[] a2 = { 'X', 1.79, d, 100 };
    object[] a1 = { 0, 'a', "objectX" };
    object[][] retVal = new object[2][];
    retVal[0] = a1;
    retVal[1] = a2;
    return retVal;
}
```

Comment: Your loop is utter nonsense. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I should have described the problem better.. Initially I wanted to put it into an existing thread. I want to iterate in a jagged array. A kind of matrix, but with rows of different length. The problem is that I cannot easily find how many rows there are. I know in this case there are 2, but I want to generalize the problem for better flexibility.

Comment: The number of 'rows' is the Length of the outer array, which you can get by calling `x.Length`

Answer (score 2):

There is no magic to this - simply check the length and avoid indexing beyond that value minus one, as you would with a one-dimensional array.

Your code looks pretty messy, are you just trying to loop over the arrays like this?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    object[][] x = weirdReturn();

    for (int i = 0; i < x.Length; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < x[i].Length; j++)
        {
            Console.Write("{0} ", x[i][j]);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("");
    }
}


static object[][] weirdReturn()
{
    DateTime d = new DateTime();
    d = DateTime.Now;
    object[] a2 = { 'X', 1.79, d, 100 };
    object[] a1 = { 0, 'a', "objectX" };
    object[][] retVal = new object[2][];
    retVal[0] = a1;
    retVal[1] = a2;
    return retVal;
}
```

Comment: x.Length is 3 in this case, and that's the length of a1. That is in fact the problem, that I need the number of rows in the matrix, which in this case is 2. I know the code is messy, and this is the reason why I don't know how to figure it out

Comment: That is not correct, `x.Length` returns 2 given the above definition of the weirdReturn method